# How to reduce the cognitive complexity of sonar for the below code?

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarqube, java-11

Below is my code and Sonar is complaining about it. Asking to make 15 and now it is 19. Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 19 to the 15 allowed. I tried with enum which is not working. And it having the transactionId as RequestParam. Is there any eclipse tool to extract this or we need to do it manually.

```
@GetMapping(value = "display",produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<RspNotification> display(@RequestParam(name = Constants.TRANSACTION_ID) final String transactionId)
    {
        List<RspNotification> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (manageProductOrderCISStore.get(transactionId) != null)
        {
            list.add(manageProductOrderCISStore.get(transactionId));
        }
        else if (manageAppointmentWWMStore.get(transactionId) != null)
        {
            list.add(manageAppointmentWWMStore.get(transactionId));
        }
        else if (manageAppointmentHWMStore.get(transactionId) != null)
        {
            list.add(manageAppointmentHWMStore.get(transactionId));
        }
        else if (manageAppointmentUnifyStore.get(transactionId) != null)
        {
            list.add(manageAppointmentUnifyStore.get(transactionId));
        }
        else if (manageAppointmentUnifyXmlStore.get(transactionId) != null)
        {
            list.add(manageAppointmentUnifyXmlStore.get(transactionId));
        }
        else if (manageProductOrderFLSStore.get(transactionId) != null)
        {
            list.add(manageProductOrderFLSStore.get(transactionId));
        }
        else if (manageProductOrderHFSStore.get(transactionId) != null)
        {
            list.add(manageProductOrderHFSStore.get(transactionId));
        }
        else if (fulfilmentQuoteEEStore.get(transactionId) != null)
        {
            list.add(fulfilmentQuoteEEStore.get(transactionId));
        }
        else if (manageInventoryHFSStore.get(transactionId) != null)
        {
            list.add(manageInventoryHFSStore.get(transactionId));
        }
        else if (manageInventoryFLSStore.get(transactionId) != null)
        {
            list.add(manageInventoryFLSStore.get(transactionId));
        }
        else if (manageBillingDocumentStore.get(transactionId) != null)
        {
            list.add(manageBillingDocumentStore.get(transactionId));
        }
        else if (serviceHealthStore.get(transactionId) != null)
        {
            list.add(serviceHealthStore.get(transactionId));
        }
        else if (fulfilmentOrderEEStore.get(transactionId) != null)
        {
            list.add(fulfilmentOrderEEStore.get(transactionId));
        }
        else if (manageWorkOrderUnifyStore.get(transactionId) != null)
        {
            list.add(manageWorkOrderUnifyStore.get(transactionId));
        }
        else if (manageDiagnosticAssuranceStore.get(transactionId) != null)
        {
            list.add(manageDiagnosticAssuranceStore.get(transactionId));
        }
        else if (materialsSupplyUnifyStore.get(transactionId) != null)
        {
            list.add(materialsSupplyUnifyStore.get(transactionId));
        }
        ///////// more if statement

        return list;
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated and enum will not work.

Comment: You have the same code copy pasted 3000 times; this is obviously wrong. So, break down what is repeated. It seems you have a clear pattern repeated - that means pull out a method. But the signature isn’t quite so simple - you’re going to need a lambda. Once you have a lambda, you can store it statically as it is a reference to behaviour rather than data … once you can store it statically. ENUM!!

Comment: You know your list always has 0 or 1 element, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a list of the maps and loop over them

```
List<Map<String, RspNotification>> maps = Arrays.asList(
    manageProductOrderCISStore,
    manageAppointmentWWMStore,
    manageAppointmentHWMStore,
    manageAppointmentUnifyStore
    //the rest
);

List<RspNotification> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map<String, RspNotification> map : maps) {
    RspNotification notification = map.get(transactionId);
    if (notification != null) {
        list.add(notification);
        return;
    }
}
return list;
```

Which you can simplify further to

```
return Stream.of(
        manageProductOrderCISStore,
        manageAppointmentWWMStore,
        manageAppointmentHWMStore,
        manageAppointmentUnifyStore
        //the rest
    )
    .map(map -> map.get(transactionId))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findFirst()
    .map(Collections::singletonList)
    .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

Comment: These are already declared as below:

 protected final Map<String, RspNotification> manageAppointmentHWMStore = new HashMap<>();
 protected final Map<String, RspNotification> manageAppointmentWWMStore = new HashMap<>();
 protected final Map<String, RspNotification> manageAppointmentUnifyStore = new HashMap<>();
 protected final Map<String, RspNotification> fulfilmentQuoteEEStore = new HashMap<>();
 protected final Map<String, RspNotification> manageInventoryFLSStore = new HashMap<>();
 protected final Map<String, RspNotification> manageInventoryHFSStore = new HashMap<>();

Comment: @AritChakraborty Not sure what you're getting at. I know they're declared like that and it doesn't change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put all these dictionaries in a list. Run a loop that tries to extract the key from each item and add it to a list.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 possibilities:

1. Loop through a list of the stores with only one if inside - if you can have a common superclass/interface, it is probably the best
2. Split the ifs: let's say that after 10, you call else {another method with the rest of the ifs}
3. Tell sonar to accept this (yes, you can do that)

I think that it is actually OK to add an exception to sonar about this one as the other, in my humble opinion, would make the code more difficult to read.